Why ViewModifier does not apply changes with EnvironmentKey?
I have this test code, I think I code everything right, but for some reasons it does not work, I mean it does not apply the modification. I cannot see the issue why?
my goal is stop repeating input value to modifier and using parent view values
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MyView(value: "Hello, world!", color: .red, border: true)
            .bordered()
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    
    let value: String
    let color: Color
    let border: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(value)
            .foregroundStyle(color)
            .environment(\.borderColor, color)
            .environment(\.isBorderEnabled, border)

    }
}

struct BorderedModifier: ViewModifier {
    
    @Environment(\.borderColor) private var color
    @Environment(\.isBorderEnabled) private var border
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        Group {
            if (border) {
                content
                    .padding(5.0)
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4)
                            .stroke(color, lineWidth: 2)
                    )
            } else {
                content
            }
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func bordered() -> some View {
        self.modifier(BorderedModifier())
    }
}


private struct BorderColorKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: Color = .black
}

private struct BorderEnabledKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: Bool = false
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var borderColor: Color {
        get { self[BorderColorKey.self] }
        set { self[BorderColorKey.self] = newValue }
    }
    
    var isBorderEnabled: Bool {
        get { self[BorderEnabledKey.self] }
        set { self[BorderEnabledKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}


It seems to be an issue of modifier ordering. If you move the .bordered() modifier into MyView and apply it before setting the environment values, it works. But the way you have it, the view modifier is not picking up environment values that were set before the view modifier was applied.

It’s better to do the if check inside padding param and overlay closure rather than outside. Ie instead of having content used on both sides of the if which breaks identity.

In my example l want values picked up automatically, so you mean inside BorderedModifier? I believe in the past I work a lot to found the best way, but not sure what you mean, do you like add your coding way and show me what you mean? Ps: I know in general what you mean, but not sure about coding in this example

This is an issue of modifier ordering. The view modifier will only pick up environment values that were set after the view modifier was applied. But the way you have it, the environment values are being set before the view modifier is applied.
You can fix by moving the .bordered() modifier into MyView:
// MyView

Text(value)
    .foregroundStyle(color)
    .bordered() //  modifier inserted here
    .environment(\.borderColor, color)
    .environment(\.isBorderEnabled, border)

// ContentView

MyView(value: "Hello, world!", color: .red, border: true)
    // .bordered() //  modifier removed from here


An alternative way to get it working is to change the logic a little.

The child view determines the color to use for the border, if enabled.
The parent view determines whether the border is enabled or not.

In fact, you already had the parent view determining whether the border is enabled or not, because you were passing a boolean flag to the child view as parameter.
So here is the updated example to show how it could work this way.

The parent view is setting the environment variable .isBorderEnabled via the View extension bordered.
To turn off the border, supply false as parameter to .bordered, or just don't call it at all.
The view modifier BorderedModifier is called by the child view via the new View extension borderColor.
The color is passed directly to the view modifier, so the environment key .borderColor is no longer needed.

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MyView(value: "The quick brown fox", color: .red)
            MyView(value: "jumps over the lazy dog", color: .blue)
        }
        .bordered()
        // .bordered(false)
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    let value: String
    let color: Color

    var body: some View {
        Text(value)
            .foregroundStyle(color)
            .borderColor(color: color)
    }
}

struct BorderedModifier: ViewModifier {
    let color: Color
    @Environment(\.isBorderEnabled) private var border

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        Group {
            if border {
                content
                    .padding(5.0)
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4)
                            .stroke(color, lineWidth: 2)
                    )
            } else {
                content
            }
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func borderColor(color: Color = .black) -> some View {
        self.modifier(BorderedModifier(color: color))
    }

    func bordered(_ enabled: Bool = true) -> some View {
        self.environment(\.isBorderEnabled, enabled)
    }
}


private struct BorderEnabledKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: Bool = false
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var isBorderEnabled: Bool {
        get { self[BorderEnabledKey.self] }
        set { self[BorderEnabledKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}



That is the way, but it is not much fun that I cannot use bordered() after MyView, do we have any other way or other idea to make this happen?

@swiftPunk The most obvious workaround would be to move the parameters into the ViewModifier, but that won't let you turn the border on or off from the parent view. Still giving it more thought in case there's another way. Ps. Thanks for accepting the answer!

The thing that I am looking is like .padding(5.0) or .foregroundStyle(color) are be able to modify view right after use. Maybe the thing i want to have is not about EnvironmentValues but I do not want make a modifier which I have to like .bordered(color: .red, border: true), I would like color and bool value for border got pick up automaticlly.

@swiftPunk Sweeper has asked a couple of questions along similar lines, see How to write a "style" view modifier that affects all the nested views of a certain type? and Where should I set the environment values so that I can read it in a CustomPresentationDetent?.

@swiftPunk Answer updated with an alternative workaround

In View extension for bordered function also in ContentView, you are passing the value as true by default, that means we are still repeating input value for modifier to work, my goal is stop repeating input value to modifier and using parent view values, I came to an answer which does not need repeat the input value.

I found a way to stop repeating input values that already exist in the parent view. I am using PreferenceKey. The limitation I see is that I must apply this modifier to the view I want to modify. Ideally, I would like to apply it once to the VStack, so that all four MyView instances would get modified. Currently, if you apply the modifier to the VStack, it treats the VStack as content and applies the modification only once. What I want, in the best possible scenario, is for the modifier to pass through the VStack and affect all MyView instances.

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            MyView(value: "The quick brown fox", color: .red, border: false)
                .bordered()
            
            MyView(value: "jumps over the lazy dog", color: .blue, border: true)
                .bordered()
            
            MyView(value: "The quick brown fox", color: .green, border: false)
                .bordered()
            
            MyView(value: "jumps over the lazy dog", color: .yellow, border: true)
                .bordered()
        }
       
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    
    let value: String
    let color: Color
    let border: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(value)
            .foregroundStyle(color)
            .preference(key: ColorPreferenceKey.self, value: color)
            .preference(key: BooleanPreferenceKey.self, value: border)

    }
}

struct BorderedModifier: ViewModifier {
    
    @State private var color: Color = Color.primary
    @State private var border: Bool = false

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        
      return Group {
            if (border) {
                content
                    .padding(5.0)
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4)
                            .stroke(color, lineWidth: 2)
                    )
            } else {
                content
            }
        }
        .onPreferenceChange(ColorPreferenceKey.self) { newValue in color = newValue }
        .onPreferenceChange(BooleanPreferenceKey.self) { newValue in border = newValue }

    }
}

extension View {
    func bordered() -> some View {
        self.modifier(BorderedModifier())
    }
}



struct ColorPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    
    static var defaultValue: Color { get { return Color.primary } }
    static func reduce(value: inout Color, nextValue: () -> Color) { value = nextValue() }
    
}

struct BooleanPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    
    static var defaultValue: Bool { get { return false } }
    static func reduce(value: inout Bool, nextValue: () -> Bool) { value = nextValue() }
    
}

